# How much to pay for hiring marshrutka in Ukraine?

Tags: buses, mountains, ukraine, shared-taxis

I was in Ukrainian mountains with the group and the **marshrutka** was hired in Lviv to transport us directly into Carpathian Mountains. This was very convenient and I've heard also it was quite cheap, however, I've not asked how much it cost.

Now I want to organize such trip myself and the people I've asked don't remember how much it costs but they say you need to negotiate this price. However, to negotiate I should know what price should I expect.

So, my question is, how much does it cost, what is the accepted rate to pay for 100km? How to estimate, what my initial proposal should be and how much would I pay?

Comment: This is not a *marshrutka*. A *marshrutka* is a small bus following fixed route just like a regular city bus. You don't hire it - you wait for it, then get inside, pay and then leave when is passes your destination. What you're referring to is a small bus used as taxi, but not *marshrutka*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that you don't have to negotiate a price - usually driver just tell the price and you accept it :)  However, you may get a "bonus" as a foreigner, but I don't expect it to be more then 20-40%.

Regarding sample price for 100 km.  According to my latest experience (and google result), MastaBaba is more-or-less right - ~30 euros for bus for 10-15 people.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an estimate:

A 250km ride in a shared taxi or marshrutka costs the equivalent of 5 - 10 euros per person, with a petrol price of about 1 euro per liter, depending on how popular and difficult the route is.

A marshrutka typically seats about 15 people, so a low estimate for renting a marshrutka for a 100km *circular* (that is, starting and finishing in the same location) drive would be:

15 * 5 / (2.5) = 30 euros.

Answer (score 4):

When I asked a taxi company for a small bus they listed 5 hryvnas/km for the whole 7-seats bus. 
There are companies that can take you over the Ukrainian border, and they charge 7 hryvnas/km for the part of trip which is not in Ukraine.